# Generated unique key in relational doctrine

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to create OneToMany relation between answers and questions tables in Doctrine. These are basic YAML schemas

Answer schema

```
  type: entity
  table: fs_answer
  fields:
    id:
      id: true
      type: integer
      unsigned: false
      nullable: false
      generator:
        strategy: IDENTITY
    questionId:
      type: integer
      unsigned: false
      nullable: false
      column: question_id
    body:
      type: text
      nullable: false
  oneToOne:
    question:
      targetEntity: FsQuestion
      cascade: {  }
      mappedBy: null
      inversedBy: null
      joinColumns:
    question_id:
      referencedColumnName: id
      orphanRemoval: false
  lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Question schema:

```
  type: entity
  table: fs_question
  fields:
    id:
      id: true
      type: integer
      unsigned: false
      nullable: false
      generator:
        strategy: IDENTITY
    body:
      type: text
      nullable: false
  oneToMany:
    answer:
      targetEntity: FsAnswer
      cascade: {  }
      mappedBy: question
      inversedBy: answers
      joinColumns:
    question_id:
      referencedColumnName: id
      orphanRemoval: false
  lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

When I update the schema with `doctrine:schema:update`, it generated the SQL code below and put `unique key` to 'question_id' in answers table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fs_answer` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `question_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `body` longtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_552D082B1E27F6BF` (`question_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

How to avoid this unique key stuff? Logically (one to many) there should not be unique key for question id in answers table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is as simple as the code below

Question:

```
oneToMany:
  answer:
    targetEntity: FsAnswer
    mappedBy: question
    cascade: ["persist"]
```

Answer:

```
manyToOne:
  question:
    targetEntity: FsQuestion
    inversedBy: answer
```

Answer (score 0):

Each answer has one and only one question right?  The fact that you defined it as oneToOne sort of confirms this.

And it looks like your joinColumn stuff is messed up.  Surprised it didn't raise errors.

Review the examples in the doctrine manual:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.1/reference/association-mapping.html

Comment: right, each answer has only one question. Actually foreign key works, however, there is unique key which I don't want

Comment: Again, you are telling doctrine to establish a OnetoOne relation from answer to question while at the same time establish a OneToMany from question to answer.  Just not going to work.  Change the OneToOne to ManyToOne and make sure you have the joinColumn defined properly.